# Precondition UML?

Tags: android-activity, uml, preconditions

I'm using [Agilian](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/product/ag/) 3.2 to build a small activity diagram. The diagram contains a couple of actions. The problem is: I'd like to display the precondition somewhere in the diagram. Is there any standard way to define preconditions for an action or activity diagram in Agilian?

Comment: You might want to visit your earlier questions and [mark a few answers as "accepted"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/135887) if they were helpful.  You also might want to [give yourself a name](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1154138).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you add a kind of pink rectangle which is a kind of note which is related to constraints. These constrains could be added on any model element. I don't know about this Agilian 3.2 tool but it should certainly be possible.
Tis is a basic modeling feature including in almost all good tools.